# searching inside vector member of struct vector

Tags: c++, boost

I have a struct like this:

```
enum crdType { CARTESIAN =0, SPHERICAL, CUSTOM1, CUSTOM2, .......};

struct customCRD {
   std::vector<coordinate> Corners;
   crdType type;
};
```

then I defined a vector < customCRD >, let's call it vec_customCRD.

I want to check if my coordinate is inside this vector or not. 
I am able to check if specific type is available:

```
vector < customCRD >::iterator iter = std::find_if(vec_customCRD.begin(), vec_customCRD.end(), boost::bind(&customCRD::type, _1) == CUSTOM1);
```

it is kind of searching a coordinate, here, inside a vector of vector.

any smart way?

**EDIT**
I forgot to mention that I cannot use C++11. and boost version higher than 1.56

I want to do following code:

```
coordinate a;  // coordinate is a class of coordinates
std::vector<coordinate> vecCrd;
vector < coordinate >::iterator Corditer;
for(vector < customCRD >::iterator iter  = vec_customCRD.begin(); iter  != vec_customCRD.end();iter++)
{
  vecCrd = iter->Corners;
  Corditer = std::find(vecCrd.begin(), vecCrd.end(), a);
  if(Corditer != vecCrd.end())
  { 
    std::cout << "yes, this is what I want" << std::endl;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you have a C++11 (or better) capable compiler, you could use [lambda expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question, I am not allowed to use C++11.

Comment: Then pass a specific function pointer, or a functor object instance. You can have any code you want to check inside that functor.

Comment: It's unclear what you want help with. Do you want help mapping coordinates? What is the `coordinate` type? Do you need help writing a function object? Had you shown the relevant code (e.g. the loop version that does what you want to achieve using std::find_if)...

Comment: The Question is been update, I hope it helps.

Comment: `std::find_if` requires a predicate. As you provide a value to search, you may use `std::find`.

Comment: And what is wrong with the code you show? It will search all items in `vec_customCRD` for a specific `coordinate`.

Comment: I wondering if I can do it in other way, less verbose, using standard features.

Comment: Not really, even if you use `std::find_if` with functors, it would be about the same amount of code. If you need to do the search from many places, put it in a function so you don't have to repeat code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use Boost Range you could write things like

```
int main() {
    std::vector<customCRD> const v;

    std::cout << "{9,10} found: " << !boost::empty(v | filtered(customCRD::havingCorner(coordinate(9,10)))) << "\n";
    std::cout << "{3,5}  found: " << !boost::empty(v | filtered(customCRD::havingCorner(coordinate(3, 5)))) << "\n";
};
```

With the predicate defined as:

```
struct customCRD {
    std::vector<coordinate> Corners;
    crdType type;

    struct havingCorner {
        coordinate _a;
        havingCorner(coordinate a) : _a(a) {}
        bool operator()(customCRD const& cc) const { return cc.Corners.end()!=std::find(cc.Corners.begin(), cc.Corners.end(), _a); }
    };
};
```

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2351267a52565b15)</kbd>** (c++11 with data)

See it **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1cd6620b19a46e0)</kbd>** (c++03)

```
#include <boost/range.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>

using namespace boost::adaptors;

#include <iostream>

enum crdType { CARTESIAN =0, SPHERICAL, CUSTOM1, CUSTOM2 };

typedef std::pair<int,int> coordinate;

struct customCRD {
    std::vector<coordinate> Corners;
    crdType type;

    struct havingCorner {
        coordinate _a;
        havingCorner(coordinate a) : _a(a) {}
        bool operator()(customCRD const& cc) const { return cc.Corners.end()!=std::find(cc.Corners.begin(), cc.Corners.end(), _a); }
    };
};

int main() {
    std::vector<customCRD> const v { 
        customCRD { {  {1,  2},  {3,  4},  {5,  6} }, CARTESIAN },
        customCRD { {  {7,  8},  {9, 10}, {11, 12} }, SPHERICAL },
        customCRD { { {13, 14}, {15, 16}, {17, 18} },   CUSTOM2 },
    };

    std::cout << "{9,10} found: " << std::boolalpha << !boost::empty(v | filtered(customCRD::havingCorner(coordinate(9,10)))) << "\n";
    std::cout << "{3,5}  found: " << std::boolalpha << !boost::empty(v | filtered(customCRD::havingCorner(coordinate(3, 5)))) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) It it possible to get iterator points to the position in the vector?

Comment: Is it possible that defined operator such that it returns iterator with respect to the position in the vector?

Comment: Can you clarify? Ah. I think I get it

Comment: actually, Knowing availability of the coordinate is not enough. I need the to iterator point to the position of the coordinate (of course if it is available). and since it is combination of vector of a vector, the iterator must not violate to the next internal vector. I hope it is more clear now. Thanks.

Comment: violate to the next internal vector?

Comment: Imagine that Having iterator (e.g. ITER) in hand, I do many search such as find_if (ITER, vectorITERbelong.end(), ......) or std::copy(vectorITERbelong.begin, ITER, ...) and etc.

Comment: Thanks, but by this we kind of do the search twice. isn't it?

Comment: @H'H Yes. What do you want. If you want to have multiple indexes on a single collection, by all means. But iterators don't (usually) link to their containers. So... What are you really trying to achieve? Drop the technicalities/accidental complexity. You have a multi-polygon and you want to check _what_ about it, actually?

Comment: yes, exactly. "iterators don't (usually) link to their containers" this is the point which made my mind busy. Thanks again for your admonition.